# Are there any good software specification/requirement tools out there?

Tags: specifications, requirements

I'm looking for a good tool for our product/design team to use when they write up the specifications (app feature requirements) for our projects. Right now we're using Word docs that are continually edited, and it's hard to keep track of what has changed when we're developing.

Answer (score 2):

You may look at [CASE Spec](http://www.analysttool.com). It is an affordable enterprise requirements specification and requirements management software.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to track changes in docs or software is the use of CVS. I used TortoiseCVS for my projects.

In other collaborative projects I used Dropbox that is a share application that also can track changes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System#IDEs_with_support_for_CVS

Comment: I'm talking about tracking changes, and visualizing the changes within the document itself. Kind of like how Microsoft Word let's you put comments in the file where changes occurred.

Comment: Tortoise permit see changes line by line in plain text files. If you need a online app take a look to Google Docs. They have control versioning.

Comment: That's fine for us devs, but our product people will have a hard time with that. I need something much simpler.

Comment: Google Docs is very simple. Did you test it?